# How can I wait till the coroutine scope execution finishes in my Android App?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to clarify one doubt regarding Kotlin Coroutines.

How can I delay the execution of the next line or next block of code in my app until the response of my ongoing API comes?

**For e.g. Suppose I want to call one API when a user opens the app and only after I get the response from that API I want to draw the views or anything else. It can be as simple as log anything or show toast or something like that.**

Note: Without using runBlocking{ } or delay() methods.

Comment: Hi and welcome Dharmesh! You will notice that no posts here carry greetings, because it will make the site a bit too bloated and those also differ across cultures, so if you want to get the best chance to get a good response here I would recommend you stick with the guidelines of no greeting in your post. (It is assumed by all of us always! ",)

Answer (score 6):

For a simple tasks you could use `invokeOnCompletion` which will execute only after the coroutine finish it's job.

Here's a little example

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //heavy calculations
    }.invokeOnCompletion { 
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Coroutine ended it's job", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer but invokeOnCompletion is also not helping my cause. Actually, I am using Retrofit to call one API in my launch scope and only after getting the response from that API, I want to execute the next block of my code. 

Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: @DharmeshBasapati so, you want to get the result from that call, yes?

Comment: You should consider using Repository pattern with a `LiveData` or `StateFlow` (StateFlow is the better way overall). See https://medium.com/swlh/repository-pattern-in-android-c31d0268118c

Comment: Okay, thanks, brother. I Will look into it and update you.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using Kotlin Coroutines is to handle certain tasks asynchronous. However you could try to start a coroutine on the fragment lifecycleScope on the main dispatcher like so:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // do api call and await
    // val result = async { // api call returning something }.await()
}
```

Comment: Note that you will block the UI thread thus user can experience bad UI behaviour

Comment: Yes but i believe that is what the OP wanted?

Comment: Hi @qki, I actually want to show the progress till the API response comes, and then and then only I want to execute the next block of my code. 

And Macksly - Is using "lifecycleScope" our only hope or we can use any scope we want or need like GlobalScope?

Comment: @DharmeshBasapati if possible it is best practise to use the lifeCycleScope of the object in which you launch your coroutine, however GlobalScope will also work :)

Comment: @Macksly I have already used async and await coroutine builder in my code but unfortunately, it is not waiting for the API response to come and just executes whatever the block of code written next after it.